# Components in SPA application (messenger like)

Tags: angular, single-page-application, angular-components

I am learning Angular 6, and I want model messenger like application and create  components correct way. I design some components in following picture.

[image]

Can you check it if I am correct? I am not sure with components D (chat conversations) and E (message replies). Is required to be such small components? What if I do bigger components like MessageRepliesComponent and ChatConversationsComponent instead? In practice it will be loop of small divs with content inside. Thanks for answers.

Comment: If you want to reuse D & E elsewhere then it makes sense to make them components. If not, it is a matter of preference really

Comment: adding to @user184994 response, another rule is simplicity. If a component class becomes too big - split it smaller independent parts.

Comment: Which program that you use to create this design?

Comment: Thank you, you are right. But components which I mentioned (reply, conversation) will be too simple in my case, which cause a lot of files with minimal code.

Comment: @MuhammedOzdogan just windows paint application